# What format is used to differntiate between plain text, contact, and image in qr code?

Tags: qr-code

Plain text, contact info, image are differences. So I want to know how to differentiate them and use them in ruby gem.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/BarcodeContents

Comment: Thank you very much. This link really helps me a lot.